# s|\b-d\b|| regex not working as expected

Tags: regex, perl

The following one liner is not working as I'd expect:

```
echo "--tags hi -d -e foo=bar" | perl -ne '$_ =~ s|\b-d\b||; print $_'
```

The "-d" remains. After looking at it for 15 minutes, I decided I should get help.

This does work ok:

```
echo "--tags hi -d -e foo=bar" | perl -ne '$_ =~ s|-d||; print $_'
```

but of course may not always work... i.e. I need word boundary markers in the search.

Comment: There's no word boundary between the space and `-` that precedes the `d`. Try `-d\b` or `(?<= )-d\b`

Comment: this is the kind of thing I'm trying to catch:
    echo "--tags a-b-c-d -d -e foo=bar" | perl -ne '$_ =~ s|\b-d\b||; print $_'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\b` does not mean is preceded or followed by whitespace, it means a word boundary (a transition into or out of a sequence of word characters); since `-` is not a word character, `\b-` means `-` has to have a word character before it.

I'm guessing maybe you mean `s|(?<!\S)-d(?!\S)||` (`-d` neither preceded nor followed by a non-whitespace character.

[See the code in use here](https://tio.run/##FYhNCoAgFAav8hVBtngnqPAQbQPxrxQiRVtKVzeDgWFGyexqtdoF9GRA9Mgzw3lIUqT/07A4QliVTK16FESbLtBtMQ4C64tcGF@6fZvIMP67lHNGTP5@MIix1g8)

Comment: you are absolutely right.  a dash does NOT belong to '\w'.  I didn't see that at first.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I've deleted my answer as it may fail against `-`

Comment: You may add this link for a working code demo if you'd like: https://tio.run/##FcJLCoAgFAXQrdwkyAZvBSUtomE/NC2DUNGG0taNDkfJZEsxu/VgRI88E@wFSYp20vgbHN4LJSNDRjDxBjmDpt4gXqTMh76aViwtaT5U89jm3CHEyz2ot6aUDw

Comment: @senor: An ASCII "word" character is very simply any alphanumeric character with the awkward addition of underscore. I can guess at what the designers were thinking, but to me it's as frustrating as `readdir` also returning `.` and `..`, which are *never* useful. It's also worth pointing out that `\b` will match a before a "word" character at the beginning of the string, or after one at the end. That is, it doesn't require a preceding or succeeding "non-word" character to kick in.

Comment: @ysth: *"It means ... a transition between word characters and non-word characters"* I often encounter this misapprehension, but as I wrote above it means `(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)`, not `(?<=\W)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\W)`.

Comment: @ysth: I was pretty sure you would know, I just wanted to leave an annotation for the benefit of the future of mankind!

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `d`, `-` isn't a word char, so use `(?<!\w)` instead of `\b`.

---

```
\b
```

means

```
# At a word char that's not preceded by a word char, or
# after a word char that's not followed by a word char.
(?<!\w)(?=\w) | (?<=\w)(?!\w)
```

so

```
\b -d \b
```

means

```
(?: (?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w) ) -d (?: (?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w) )
```

Since `-` isn't a word char, and since `d` is a word char, the above simplifies to the following:

```
(?<=\w) -d (?!\w)
```

If `-` was a word char, the above would simplify to the following instead:

```
(?<!\w) -d (?!\w)
```

That is what you want, or just

```
(?<!\w) -d \b
```

(*Spaces added for readability. Either remove the spaces or use `/x`.*)